# Unit Testing Mock Guzzle Response

Tags: 8, testing

I'm trying to test a method that makes an HTTP request via Guzzle, so I can see if my code that filters that response is working. I have a mock json response in a json file that I want to use to test it. This is simply a saved version of an actual response.

I know you can mock methods e.g. this would override the get method to return a mock Guzzle Response. How do you mock a Guzzle response in Drupal 8?

```
    $this->mockHttp->expects($this->any())
      ->method('get')
      ->willReturn($mockGuzzleResponseShouldGoHere);
```

The mock Guzzle response needs to have a mock method getBody so I can do something like this:

```
$this->mockHttp->expects($this->any())
      ->method('getBody')
      ->willReturn(__DIR__ . 'Mocks/membership-classes.json');
```

and make sure that getBody returns my mock json file.

**Method to test that makes a Http Guzzle request**

```
<?php 

/**
   * Call the GetMembershipClasses service.
   *
   * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse
   */
  public function getMembershipClasses() {

    try {
      // Load configuration for this module.
      $response = $this->http_client->get(
        $this->getBaseUrl() . '/2014/06/membershipClasses', [
          'headers' => $this->getAnonymousHeaders(),
        ]);

        $response = json_decode($response->getBody());

        // Get to the meat of the response.
        $response = $response->GetMembershipClassesResponseMessage->MembershipClasses->MembershipClass;

        // Validate returned data.
        $filtered = array();
        foreach ($response as $membership_class) {
          $membership_class->MembershipClassCode = $this->removeSpaces($membership_class->MembershipClassCode);
          if ($membership_class->IsActive === TRUE) {
            $filtered[] = $membership_class;
          }
        }
        return new JsonResponse($filtered);
    }
    catch (RequestException $e) {
      return $this->handleError($e);
    }

  }
```

**And the test class**

```
<?php

/**
 * Class RouteControllerAnonymousTest.
 *
 */
class AnonymousWebServicesTest extends UnitTestCase {

  /**
   * Mock of http_client service.
   *
   * @var \GuzzleHttp\Client
   */
  protected $mockHttp;

  /**
   * Mock of state service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\State\State
   */
  protected $mockState;

  /**
   * Mock of config.factory service.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactory
   */
  protected $mockConfigFactory;

  /**
   * Set up method which is called before any tests are
   * run. Mocks of the services that the class being tested rely on are
   * created.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  protected function setUp() {

    parent::setUp();
    $mockHttp = $this
      ->getMockBuilder('GuzzleHttp\Client')
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->setMethods(['get', 'getBody'])
      ->getMock();
    $this->mockHttp = $mockHttp;

    $mockState = $this
      ->getMockBuilder('Drupal\Core\State\State')
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();
    $this->mockState = $mockState;

    $mockConfigFactory = $this
      ->getMockBuilder('\Drupal\Core\Config\ConfigFactory')
      ->disableOriginalConstructor()
      ->getMock();
    $this->mockConfigFactory = $mockConfigFactory;

  }

  /**
   * Test the getMembershipClasses method.
   */
  public function testGetMembershipClasses() {

    // This needs to mock a Guzzle response from a get request
    $this->mockHttp->expects($this->any())
      ->method('get')
      ->willReturn('The mock guzzle response should go here);

    $this->mockHttp->expects($this->any())
      ->method('getBody')
      ->willReturn(__DIR__ . 'Mocks/membership-classes.json');

    $anonymousWebServices = new AnonymousWebServices(
      $this->mockHttp,
      $this->mockState,
      $this->mockConfigFactory
    );

    $membership_classes = $anonymousWebServices->getMembershipClasses();
    var_dump($membership_classes);
    // Insert some assert statement here

  }

}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Guzzle includes a mock handler that lets you provide a mock HTTP response. Docs are at http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/testing.html. Here's how you might use it in your unit test:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client as HttpClient;
use GuzzleHttp\Handler\MockHandler;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;

/**
 * Test the getMembershipClasses method.
 */
public function testGetMembershipClasses() {

  $body = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/Mocks/membership-class.json');
  // This sets up the mock client to respond to the first request it gets
  // with an HTTP 200 containing your mock json body.
  $mock = new MockHandler([
    new Response(200, [], $body),
  ]);
  $handler = HandlerStack::create($mock);
  $this->mockHttp = new HttpClient(['handler' => $handler]);

  $anonymousWebServices = new AnonymousWebServices(
    $this->mockHttp,
    $this->mockState,
    $this->mockConfigFactory
  );

  $membership_classes = $anonymousWebServices->getMembershipClasses();
  $membership_classes = json_decode($membership_classes->getContent());

  $this->assertNotEmpty($membership_classes);
  foreach ($membership_classes as $membership_class) {
    $this->assertTrue($membership_class->IsActive === TRUE);

  }

}
```

You can queue multiple mock responses by adding them to your handler at creation time:

```
  $mock = new MockHandler([
    new Response(200, [], $body),
    new Response(400, [], 'Request malformed.'),
  ]);
```

Or you can add them after your client has already been instantiated, as long as you keep a reference to your mock handler around. If you have multiple test methods, this is a lot easier to read and maintain:

```
public function setUp() {
  $this->mockHandler = new MockHandler();
  $handler = HandlerStack::create($this->mockHandler);
  $this->mockHttp = new HttpClient(['handler' => $handler]);
}

public function testSomething() {
  $this->mockHandler->append(new Response(200, [], 'apples and bananas'));
  $responseBody = $this->mockHttp->get('http://example.com')->getBody();
  $this->assertEquals($responseBody, 'apples and bananas');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So this might not be best practice but it does work. I will leave it open for a while if someone has a better answer but this is what I did:

Because the guzzle get() method should return a response object and the code that I'm testing uses the getBody() method of that object I created a mock class for this response with just one method - getBody() - which returns my mock data. I then pass an instance of the MockResponse class as the return value of my mock of the get() method from the mockHttp class.

So, there's probably a more elegant way but it does the job!

```
  /**
   * Test the getMembershipClasses method.
   */
  public function testGetMembershipClasses() {

    $mockResponse = new MockResponse(__DIR__ . '/Mocks/membership-class.json');

    $this->mockHttp->expects($this->any())
      ->method('get')
      ->willReturn($mockResponse);

    $anonymousWebServices = new AnonymousWebServices(
      $this->mockHttp,
      $this->mockState,
      $this->mockConfigFactory
    );

    $membership_classes = $anonymousWebServices->getMembershipClasses();
    $membership_classes = json_decode($membership_classes->getContent());

    $this->assertNotEmpty($membership_classes);
    foreach ($membership_classes as $membership_class) {
      $this->assertTrue($membership_class->IsActive === TRUE);

    }

  }

}

/**
 * Class MockResponse.
 *
 * @package Drupal\Tests\hambs_api_wrapper\Controller\Unit
 */
class MockResponse {

  private $filePath;

  /**
   * @param {string} $filePath
   *   - The file path where the mock test file lives.
   */
  public function __construct($filePath) {
    $this->filePath = $filePath;
  }

  /**
   * Mocking the Guzzle getBody() method.
   *
   * @return string
   */
  public function getBody() {

    $file_location = $this->filePath;
    $file_handler = fopen($file_location, "r");
    $file = fread($file_handler, filesize($file_location));
    fclose($file_handler);

    return $file;

  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\Handler\MockHandler;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response;
use GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request;
use GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException;

// Create a mock and queue two responses.
$mock = new MockHandler([
    new Response(200, ['X-Foo' => 'Bar'], 'Hello, World'),
    new Response(202, ['Content-Length' => 0]),
    new RequestException('Error Communicating with Server', new Request('GET', 'test'))
]);

$handlerStack = HandlerStack::create($mock);
$client = new Client(['handler' => $handlerStack]);

// The first request is intercepted with the first response.
$response = $client->request('GET', '/');
echo $response->getStatusCode();
//> 200
echo $response->getBody();
//> Hello, World
// The second request is intercepted with the second response.
echo $client->request('GET', '/')->getStatusCode();
//> 202

// Reset the queue and queue up a new response
$mock->reset();
$mock->append(new Response(201));

// As the mock was reset, the new response is the 201 CREATED,
// instead of the previously queued RequestException
echo $client->request('GET', '/')->getStatusCode();
//> 201
```